# C# Compiler's null state static analysis when validating objects

Tags: c#, nullable, static-analysis, non-nullable

I have enabled Nullable check in my project and in a lot of places in the code I check input object and its properties and throw exception if something is wrong. But if everything is all right then I'm certain that input object is not null. Is there a way to tell this to compiler, to somehow use NotNullWhen attribute or something like that? I don't want to disable nullable check anywhere in the code.

```
void Validate(MyClass1? obj1, MyClass2 obj2)
{
    if (obj1 == null || obj2 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
}

void DoSomething(MyClass1 obj1, MyClass2 obj2)
{
    // This method requires not-null objects
    ...
}

void Process(MyClass1? obj1, MyClass2 obj2)
{
    Validate(obj1, obj2);
    
    // this produces warning, requires to explicitly check if both objects are not null
    DoSomething(ob1, obj2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`NotNullAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute?view=netcore-3.1) from `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis` namespace:

> Specifies that an output is not null even if the corresponding type allows it. Specifies that an input argument was not null when the call returns.

```
void Validate([NotNull] MyClass1? obj1, [NotNull] MyClass2 obj2)
{
    ...
}
```

Also [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/#nullable-postconditions-maybenull-and-notnull) article can be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it's what I need. I was confused because documentation always uses [NotNull] with ref arguments. But it seems it works also with regular class arguments.

Comment: @FrodoBaggins was glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

I think `[NotNull]` and. `[ItemNotNull]` Attribute﻿s are what you're looking for. See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute?view=netcore-3.1) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html).

#### NotNullAttribute﻿

Indicates that the value of the marked element can never be null.

(Example﻿)

```
[NotNull] object Foo() {
  return null; // Warning: Possible 'null' assignment
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this example marks return value as [NotNull]. I needed something for arguments.